# SP2013 - Need to check calculated field from another list

Tags: sharepoint-fields

I needed to check the value of a choice field from ListA when displaying some form fields in ListB.  Since choice fields are not available as LookUp fields, I made the value of the Choice field equal to a new Calculated field I added to ListA.

My plan was to use JQuery in a CEWP to on the Edit and New Forms in ListB to check the value of the Calculated field.  I added the LookUp to ListB and chose my ListA calculated field in the "Add a column to show each of these additional fields" option.  But that field does not show up in the Edit and New Forms so I don't have anything to check.  What can I do?

Thank you!